# Python coverage in Gitlab CI not showing any percentages

Tags: python, code-coverage, gitlab-ci, coverage.py

I am trying to make test coverage work for a python project. And I simply cannot figure out why there is no percentage showing neither in the tests nor the badge.

The command `coverage report` is called produces this output in the log:

```
[...]
tests/__init__.py              0      0   100%
tests/test_ml_squarer.py       4      0   100%
tests/test_squarer.py          4      0   100%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL                         17      2    88%
test_service run-test: commands[4] | coverage xml
```

and depending on the `regex`-expression that is saved in *General > CI/CD*, it simply looks for the `88%` next to `TOTAL`. I used the recommended one for *pytest-cov (Python)* , i.e. `^TOTAL.+?(\d+\%)$` which works according to a regex checker.

[image: regex expression]

I also run `coverage xml` together with

```
artifacts:
    reports:
        cobertura: coverage.xml
```

which results in a successful upload of the file but I dont think this would be necessary for showing the basic percentages:

```
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=29421 revision=05161b14 version=12.4.1
coverage.xml: found 1 matching files               
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=8996 responseStatus=201 Created token=DXpxsGiF
```

Either way, it is not working for me using: *GitLab Community Edition 12.10.11*. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, a friend of mine was able to help, referencing:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/48613

So in the end the `regex` didn't fit even though it looks like it would. I guess what made it even more difficult was the other `regex` was recommended by Gitlab itself.

The correct regex is:
`*TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$*`

[image: TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$]

As you can see, there is no (visual) difference to the one above...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following regex:

```
TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)
```

It is very similar to the one from @Thomas L. I had to remove the trailing `$`.

It matches the following correctly:

```
src/name/folder/script.py                                     38      4    89%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                        732    227    69%
============================= 226 passed in 1.86s ==============================
```

[image: Matches 69% from the coverage logs]

And it shows perfectly under the pipeline status:

[image: 69% is displayed correctly under the pipeline check]